# Opera, зазор в верстке

Tags: opera, вёрстка

Справа, в опере, появляется зазор между картинками в пиксель, если изменять размер окна браузера, то зазор этот исчезает. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

[Шаблон](http://vk.cc/STEjl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Углубленно искать проблему не стал, но такой способ помог. У меня в Opera 12.00 показывает нормально без полоски.

```
.wrapper {
width: 908px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
right: -1px
}
```

Лучше было бы добавить к input такое свойство

```
input {
    outline: none
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, поставил пока хак на js чтоб только для оперы добавлял этот css дабы в других браузерах картина не портилась.

Comment: Да вроде в других не портится, там смещение всего лишь 1px.

Comment: Если для всех браузерах применять, то для тех браузеров где было нормально это смешение в 1px портит, получается зазор с другой стороны :)